# isDynamic and contactDelegate in SpriteKit and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

In my program, I need to check if two non-dynamic nodes contact or contain each other on update to remove one. I am aware that you cannot test for contact when both nodes are not dynamic. These local variable nodes are created within a method so I have to use the node's .name property to check them with each other. Is there a way to test for contact or if they contain each other on update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Each node has a frame which is a `CGRect`. There are various methods that are callable on a CGRect such as `intersects` and `contains` which will tell you if two CGRects overlap or if one contains the other:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect/1454747-intersects

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect/1454186-contains

Comment: How can I implement this with a SKSpriteNode, with no texture but just a circular physics body?

Comment: When you say it has no texture, do you mean you didn’t assign it a texture (it which case it’s just a coloured shape?), or that it has size (0, 0)? Either way, it should still have a `frame` property which is a `CGRect`.